# How to use axios to fetch data from servlet and then crossfilter it and display via highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, axios, crossfilter

I am trying to display charts through highcharts with data from my servlet, but somehow it's not able to display data properly from my servlet(like its showing in console but after that I think I'm missing few steps). I am totally new to react js and this web development stuff, please help, I think its something with axios,

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchPanel from '../components/SearchPanel'
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import crossfilter from 'crossfilter2';
import axios from 'axios';
import App1 from '../components/App1';



export default class AnalyticsSection extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    dataResults: [],
    data : [],
  };

  
  
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/Internship_Backend/customer')
     .then(response => {
       console.log(response);
       this.setState({ dataResults : response.data });
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
     });
    
     var dataset = crossfilter(this.state.dataResults);
   
     var bcodedim = dataset.dimension(d => d.business_code);
     var bcodegrp = bcodedim.group().reduceSum(d => d.actualOpenAmount);

     function prepareDataForHighcharts(groups){
      var categories =[];
      var data = [];
      var gdata = groups.top(4);
      gdata.forEach(d => {
          categories.push(d.key);
          data.push(d.value);

      });
      return{
          categories : categories,
          data : data
      }
  }

  var tempObject = prepareDataForHighcharts(bcodegrp);
  var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo : 'container',
        type : 'bar',
        backgroundColor:'#1b1f38',
        minWidth: 275,
        height: '222px',
       
        
    },
    // colors: ['#FFFFFFa5 '],

    title : {
        text : "Total Amount by Company Code",
        style:{
            color: '#FFFFFFa5'
        }

    },
    xAxis : {
       
        type : 'category',
        categories : tempObject.categories,
        title: {
          text: null
      },
      overflow : 'auto'
        
    },
    yAxis : {
      min: 0,
      // overflow : 'scroll'
      // tickInterval: 10000,
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' dollars'
    },
    series : [{
        // name : 'Count',
        data : tempObject.data,
        // data: [125, 100,85, 74, ]
    }],
    legend : {
      enabled : false,
    },
    credits: {
       enabled : false,
      },
    exporting: {
       enabled : false,
         },
        
     plotOptions: {
       
      }
    }
    

var chart = new Highcharts.chart(options);


}  
 

  

  render (){
    

  return (
       <Grid container  >
          
          <Grid item xs style={{
              minWidth: 275,
              height: '225px',
              margin: '2px 2px 10px ',
              backgroundColor: "rgb(93,175,240,0.5)",
              marginTop:'-10px',
              marginLeft : '12px',
              marginRight : '-5px'
           
           }} >
             <div id = 'container' align='center' style = {{ marginTop : '2px' }}> </div>
           </Grid>
        
        <Grid item xs style = {{
          minWidth: 275,
          height: '225px',
          margin: '2px 2px 10px ',
          backgroundColor: "rgb(93,175,240,0.5)",
          marginTop:'0px',
          marginLeft : '12px',
          marginRight : '-5px'
           }} >
             <SearchPanel/>
            < div align='center'>
              
              </div>
        </Grid>


        </Grid>
   
      
    
  );
}
}
```

the data in my servlet is in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would process data further in the `then` callback and then store results in state.

```js
const url = (() => {
  const data = [{"pk_id":1,"acct_doc_header_id":539592086,"company_id":60,"document_number":39439082,"document_number_norm":39439082,"business_code":"pier9","create_year":"","document_line_number":0,"doctype":"RI","customer_number":218994,"customer_number_norm":218994,"fk_customer_map_id":-1,"customer_name":"pied piper","division":"","documentCreateDate":"Jul 5, 2018","documentCreateDateNorm":"Jul 5, 2018","posting_id":"","invoice_id":39439082,"invoice_id_norm":39439082,"totalOpenAmount":0.0,"totalOpenAmountNorm":0.0,"cust_payment_terms":60,"business_area":"","ship_to":"","clearingDate":"Sep 5, 2018","clearingDateNorm":"Sep 5, 2018","reason_code":"","isOpen":0,"debit_credit_indicator":"","payment_method":"","invoiceAmountDocCurrency":3925.91,"document_id":539592086,"actualOpenAmount":3925.91,"paidAmount":3925.91,"dayspast_due":2,"invoice_age":62,"disputed_amount":0.0}]
  const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], {
    type: 'application/json'
  })
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
})()

const options = ({data, categories}) => ({
  chart: {
      type : 'bar',
      backgroundColor:'#1b1f38',
      minWidth: 275,
      height: '222px',              
  },
  title : {
      text : "Total Amount by Company Code",
      style:{
          color: '#FFFFFFa5'
      }
  },
  xAxis : {
      type : 'category',
      categories,
      title: {
        text: null
    },
    overflow : 'auto'

  },
  yAxis : {
    min: 0,
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' dollars'
  },
  series : [{
      data
  }],
  legend : {
    enabled : false,
  },
  credits: {
     enabled : false,
    },
  exporting: {
    enabled : false,
  },
  plotOptions: {}
})

const prepareDataForHighcharts = (groups) => {
  const categories = [];
  const data = [];
  const gdata = groups.top(4);
  for(const {key, value} of gdata) {
    categories.push(key);
    data.push(value);
  }
  
  return {
    categories,
    data
  }
}

const ReactHighcharts = ReactHighcharts;
const { Component, useState, useEffect } = React;

class AnalyticsSection extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataResults: [],
      config: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true;
    
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          const dataResults = response.data;
         
          if(!this.mounted) {
            return;
          }
          
          const dataset = crossfilter(dataResults);
          const bcodedim = dataset
            .dimension(({business_code}) => business_code);
          const bcodegrp = bcodedim.group()
            .reduceSum(({actualOpenAmount}) => actualOpenAmount);
          const obj = prepareDataForHighcharts(bcodegrp);
          const config = options(obj);
          
          this.setState(state => ({
            isLoading: false,
            config
          }));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false;
  }
  
  render() {
    const { isLoading, config } = this.state;
  
    return <div>
    {isLoading ? <div>Loading</div> : <ReactHighcharts config = {config}></ReactHighcharts>}
  </div>
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <AnalyticsSection />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-highcharts@16.0.2/bundle/ReactHighcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/crossfilter2@latest/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: my bad, I should have specified more clearly, by just one record I meant that for example the data in my servlet is like in that form, but it actually contains 50,000  records in the same form and also, will it be possible without hooks, we aren't allowed to use that. :(

Comment: I am not using any hooks there. Number of records doesnt matter as you're interested in computing final config so you can pass it to `ReactHighcharts` component

Comment: took me 22 hours to understand but it actually worked, did a little bit of tweaking, and called the function in `then` block and it's actually showing now, thanks a lot.